# What is the right direction to finding $\int {\sqrt{x^4+x^{-4}+2}\over x^5}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

$\int {\sqrt{x^4+x^{-4}+2}\over x^5}$. I started Calculus 2 yesterday so I am not really advanced. It was given as an exercise and I can't seem to solve it. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**: $$x^4+x^{-4}+2=x^{-4}\left((x^4)^2 +2x^4+1\right)$$
Can you factorise this polynomial? (Try replacing $x^4$ by $y$ if you get stuck)

Comment: I didn't understand how you got $2x^4+1$... Trying to multiply it again I get something else...

Comment: I've switched the order on the right hand side to make the factorisation clearer. Try multiplying out the right hand side.

Comment: Same problem I had with Jose's reply-this seems like a lot of work for such a simple algebra problem. We should save our brains for when they're needed. : )

Answer (score 6):

First you should notice that $x^4 + 2 +x^{-4}=x^4 + 2x^2x^{-2}  +x^{-4}  = (x^2+x^{-2})^2$ then you can do some simplifying of the expression and brake up into smaller parts to integrate.

Comment: Uh-since the expression under the square root is a polynomial, can't you simply take the power of 1/2 and use the laws of exponents to simplify the whole thing? This seems like a lot of work for something so basic.

Comment: what do you mean take the power of 1/2, exactly?

Comment: Be careful with the "laws of exponents"  since $\sqrt{(a + b)} \neq \sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b}$

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all,you have to simplify the numerator and this is where your basic skills in high school algebra come in.

$$\int {\sqrt{x^4+x^{-4}+2}\over x^5}dx= \int {{(x^4+x^{-4}+2})^{\frac{1}{2}}\over x^5}dx$$
$$=\int {{(x^2+x^{-2}})\over x^5}dx$$=
$$ \int{(x^{-3}+x^{-7})} dx $$

Now you simply integrate as antiderivatives.

$\int{(x^{-3}+ x^{-7}})$ = $-4x^{-4}+ -6 x^{-6} + C$

Comment: this is wrong, please correct: $\sqrt{2}$ should not be there.

Comment: ps: I did not downvote. This is a typo that could easily be fixed.

Comment: Notice that $(a+b)^k\not=a^k+b^k$ in general for $k\not=1$,you can easily see this holds for $k=1/2$ with $a=9,b=16,k=1/2$

Comment: It should be correct now as $(x^2 + x^{-2})^2$ = $x^4+x^{-4}+2$. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You could start by substituting $u = x^{-4}$ and $du = -4x^{-5} dx$. Then your integral becomes
$$
-\frac{1}{4} \int \sqrt{\frac{1}{u} + u + 2} du = -\frac{1}{4} \int \sqrt{\frac{u^2 + 2u + 1}{u}} du = -\frac{1}{4} \int u^{-1/2}(u+1) du
$$
Now distribute and integrate!